# Array.push is not a function with return Array

Tags: javascript

Im having problem when im Inputing to my Textarea a different character. That the .push method is not a function error. I cant seem to find a Solution.

```
updatestats(){
           //sample input
        let input = "aab";
        let collectionresult = [];
        for(let i=0;i < input.length;i++)
        {
            let char = input[i];
            collectionresult = this.checkuniqueness(collectionresult,char);
            
        }        
        console.log(collectionresult);
    }
    checkuniqueness(collection, character) {
        let update = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
            if (collection[i].character === character) {
                collection = {
                    character: character,
                    number: collection[i].number + 1
                }
                update = true;
            }
        }
        if (update === false) {
            collection.push({
                character: character,
                number: 1
            });

        }

        return collection;
    }
```

Comment: Because `collection` isn't an array anymore: `collection = { ... }`

Comment: If `.push` is not a function, what you are applying it to is not an array. So look at what it *is*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you're replacing the `collections` array with a single object containing the updated element for the given character. You should just update that element in place rather than reassign the array itself by replacing that assignment with:

```
collections[i].number++;
```

Your function can also be simplified by replacing the loop with the `find()` method.

```
checkuniqueness(collection, character) {
  let counter = collection.find(o => o.character == character);
  if (counter) {
    counter.number++;
  } else {
    collection.push({
      character: character,
      number: 1
    });
  }

  return collection;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first function you set the collection variable to be an array but in the second function you are changing the type of the 'collection' variable to be an object but push() is only defined for arrays, so this cannot work :

```
    collection = {
        character: character,
        number: collection[i].number + 1
    }
```

Comment: so you mean that it is not updating the existing object in the array.

Comment: @johhny It's replacing the entire array with this object. You meant to assign to `collection[i]` rather than `collection`.

Comment: But you should just increment the counter: `collection[i].number++;`

Comment: so the type of the array can change to a object even if it is declared as an Array.